# R: How to create a equal blocks of variables randomly?

Tags: r, block, sample

I have a data frame of n = 20 variables (number of columns) spread over b = 5 blocks (4 variables per block).
I would like to create p = 4 **random and equal sized blocks** of variables **from the 5 blocks of variables.**

I tried :

```
sample (x = 1: p, size = n, replace = TRUE) 
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Example of expected result (5 variables per block):

```
[1] 4 1 2 1 4 2 3 1 2 3 2 1 4 3 1 2 3 3 4 4
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
sample(x = rep(1:p,n/p), size = n, replace = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having discussed this in comments below, here is a solution:

Create a vector that looks like what you want, and then use `sample` to randomly sort it by sampling the whole vector without replacement:

```
p <- 4
b <- 5

sample(rep(1:p, b), size = p * b)

[1] 3 1 4 3 3 4 1 1 4 2 2 4 3 2 1 2 2 4 3 1
```

Comment: I tried :     rapply(as.list(rep(4,b)),function(X) sample(x = 1:p, size = X, replace = TRUE)) , but it doesn't work!!

Comment: `rep` is a good start, but if you make the vector the right length, why replace?

Comment: Actually, I have 100 variables spread over 5 blocks (20 variables per block) so if I use as.list (rep (20,5))  and sample (x = 1: 4 .. ..  I have to use replace = TRUE

Comment: Perhaps you mean `rep(1:20, 5)`? And how long is that vector?

Comment: The length of the vector is 100 spread over 5 blocks (20 variables per block). So i use : rapply(as.list(rep(20,5)),function(X) sample(x = 1:4, size = X, replace = TRUE))  
  [1] 3 4 4 3 2 2 4 1 3 1 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 3 2 2 2 4 4 2 4 1 2 2 3 1 1 3 3 1 2 2 4 4 1 1 4 3 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 3 1 1 3 2 4 3 3 3 4 1 4 3 2 2 1 3 4 2 4 2 3 2 4 1 3 2 4 4 1 4 4 3 1 2 4 1 4 2 2 3 4 1 2 3 3 3 3 2 4 4

Comment: Instead of sampling from `1:4`, sample from `rep(20, 5)` (which will also allow you to drop the `rapply` structure).

Comment: if i use : sample(x = rep(20,5), size = 25, replace = TRUE) 
or
sample(x =1:4, size = rep(20, 5), replace = TRUE) 
 [1] 4 3 1 4 2 2 4 2 3 1 2 4 1 1 1 3 1 4 4 3
Doesn't solve my problem !

Comment: Where did `size = 25` come from? Don't you want 100? Maybe I don't understand your problem.

Comment: in total I have 100 variables  spread over 5 blocks 
and in the end I want to have 4 blocks (25 variables per block)

Comment: Ah sorry I made a mistake earlier, should have said sample from `rep(1:4, 25)`

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution.